# How to enter BIOS on Lenovo T400?

Tags: ubuntu, bios, thinkpad

How shall I enter BIOS on Lenovo T400, in order to change the beep option in configuration?

I am now running Ubuntu 12.04. Can I change the configuration without restarting the OS?

Comment: What keys have you tried exactly? F2 or ThinkAdvanage button works for me

Comment: I haven't. Can i enter bios and change its configuration without restarting my OS?

Answer (score 1):

During boot, repeatedly tap (spam) <kbd>F1</kbd>.  However, some generations may change the key, so you could try going up the line if that fails, and onto <kbd>DEL</kbd>.

This must be done from being shut down/restarted.

Source: I have a t530 and it was the same as the t400 my buddy has.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change BIOS setting while the machine is running. You need to shutdown or restart.

To get into the BIOS setup for the T400 you need to hit the ThinkVantage button, its the small blue bar button at the top of the keyboard. Doing this will interrupt the normal boot sequence and you will be given a menu of options. One of the options is to enter BIOS setup. I believe the key is F1.